# A parallelogram is inscribed in a rectangle

Tags: calculus

A parallelogram is inscribed in a rectangle such that its vertices are the midpoints of the sides of the rectangle. If the area of the parallelogram is 60, and one of the dimensions of the rectangle is 12, what is the other dimension of the rectangle?
[image]

Comment: What did you try? Did you draw a diagram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Use this picture to calculate the area of the rectangle. Once you have that, the other dimension is just $\frac{\text{Area}}{12}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

- Knowing the area of the parallelogram is $60$, what is the area of the rectangle?